# Showing that if $|N(u) \cap N(v)|=1 $ then Graph G is r regular.

Tags: graph-theory

Show that for any graph $G$ if and for verticies $u,v$ in G then if $|N(u) \cap N(v)|=1 $ then Graph G is r regular. $N(u)$ means the neighborhood of u all the vertices which are adjacent to u.

r regular means that every vertex in graph G has the same number of neighbors. I am not sure how I would I show this. How to start this proof.

Comment: I assume $u$ and $v$ are distinct?

Comment: Yes they are distict

Comment: The friendship graph satisfies this condition, and is not regular.  So there might be something missing in your statement.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendship_graph#Friendship_theorem